# how to expand an array elements as separate parameters to a function

Tags: php, arrays, function, graph

I have an array of colors having dynamic values which depends on database. now these values are required in a function which takes values only like this function('para1','para2','para3','para4')
 where param1 to param4 are color values in an array.
Problem is how can i parse these values to that function in the above stated format.Only a programminng logic required.Language is php.

Suppose dynamic array is color[]=('red','maroon','blue','green');
and these value should be passed to this function like :setLineColor('red','maroon','blue','green');

I m using this function for creating graphs.(Lib using PHP_graphlib: link: http://www.ebrueggeman.com/phpgraphlib/documentation.php)
Any other suggested library is welcomed.Plz provide a simple example with it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the function [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php).

```
<?php
$colors = array('red','maroon','blue','green');
call_user_func_array('setLineColor', $colors);
?>
```

If you want to call the method of an object, you can use this instead:

```
<?php
$graph = new ...
$colors = array('red','maroon','blue','green');
call_user_func_array(array($graph, 'setLineColor'), $colors);
?>
```

Comment: yes enrico...thanks for that fruity response..sorry,i didnt mentioned that it is a method of some library.

Answer (score 38):

Since PHP 5.6 you can use [argument unpacking](http://php.net/functions.arguments#functions.variable-arg-list) with the triple-dot-operator:

```
setLineColor(...$colors);
```

Comment: Very nice, much easier on the eyes as `call_user_func_array` and also practical, if you want to combine "fixed" args with arrays like `fprintf(STDOUT, $format,...$args)`

Answer (score -5):

```
function($color[0], $color[1], $color[2], $color[3])
```

Comment: Worst answer....I think u didnt read thats color values are not fixed..they vary depending on database values...

Comment: I know they're not fixed - that's why I'm referencing the array, which contains the dynamic values.

Comment: This answer doesn't work if you don't know the number of values in advance.  It's also a bad solution if the array has, say, 500 values.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, but that wasn't a part of the original question

Comment: I agree with adam. In the question, the number of arguments IS known. So this is the best answer. No need to call "call_user_func_array" in such a case.