# pass array of conditions to doctrine expr()->orx() method

Tags: php, oop, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

I need to construct DQL with a `QueryBuilder` like this

```
[QUERY]... AND WHERE e.type = x OR e.type = Y OR e.type = N [...]
```

I have types in array How can I pass this array to my query builder?

```
$qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->orx(CONDITIONS));
```

List of types will be dynamic, calling `$qb->andWhere` on each foreach types loop will make only more AND WHERE's no more ORs. 
Can I store multiply `orx` expressions and then add it to `andWhere`? Any idea how to solve this, probably, common problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I knew that tommarow gonna be a better day.
The solution is simple. Your can make array of OR expressions like so

```
$ors[] = $qb->expr()->orx('e.type = '.$qb->expr()->literal($value));
```

And then just add it to andWhere()/Where() method of the query builder via join method like so:

```
$qb->andWhere(join(' OR ', $ors));
```

Answer (score 88):

I hope so, then I found this :

```
$conditions = array('e.type = x', 'e.type = Y', 'e.type = N');
$orX = $qb->expr()->orX();

foreach ($conditions as $condition) {
    $orX->add($condition);
}

$qb->add('where', $orX);
```

Using @meze suggestion, you can simplify the code and replace the *foreach* statement with:

```
$orX->addMultiple($conditions);
```

Comment: Each day is better than before, foreach can be replaced with `$orX->addMultiple($conditions);`

Comment: I've change the answer to community wiki. @meze, you're welcome to edit it with your changes.

Answer (score 15):

@DEY his answer can be simplified.
No need for the foreach, this also works:

```
$conditions = array('e.type = x', 'e.type = Y', 'e.type = N');

$orX = $qb->expr()->orX();
$orX->addMultiple($conditions);

$qb->where($orX);
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also use `...` in php like:

```
$conditions = array('e.type = x', 'e.type = Y', 'e.type = N');
$criteria = Criteria::create();
$criteria->andWhere(Criteria::expr()->orX(...$conditions));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) function [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026983/how-to-expand-an-array-elements-as-separate-parameters-to-a-function).

It lets you call a method passing an array's items as parameters.

For example:

```
$conditions = array('e.type = x', 'e.type = Y', 'e.type = N');
$expr = $qb->expr();
call_user_func_array(array($expr, 'orX'), $conditions);
```