# How to change order of commands in doctrine Criteria

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

So this is how I use criteria:

```
$criteria = Criteria::create();
$criteria->andWhere($criteria->expr()->eq('author', /**/));
$criteria->orWhere($criteria->expr()->eq('author', /**/));
$criteria->orWhere($criteria->expr()->eq('author', /**/));
```

which results in this sql command:

```
WHERE 

      (
        (
          t0.author_id = ? 
          OR t0.author_id = ?
        ) 
        OR t0.author_id = ?
      )
```

What if I need this?

```
WHERE 

      (
        (
          t0.author_id = ? 
          OR t0.author_id = ?
          OR t0.author_id = ?
        )
      )
```

Is there any way how I can change the association of brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$criteria = Criteria::create();
$criteria->andWhere(
    $criteria->expr()->orX(
        $criteria->expr()->eq('author', /**/),
        $criteria->expr()->eq('author', /**/),
        $criteria->expr()->eq('author', /**/)
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way how can i find whether criteria found anything ? As far as i know, they simply dont filter anything and acts like as they dont work if they did not found match.

Comment: I'm not an expert with Criteria, but in a query, I think I would do it using a left join, testing if the result is null...

Comment: I have little problem. I need to generate internal expressions like this:

    foreach($filter->getFilterAuthors() as $author) {
                        $criteria->expr()->eq('author', $author);
                    } Which doesnt work with orX() function that needs parameters.

Comment: Take a look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704447/pass-array-of-conditions-to-doctrine-expr-orx-method. Use the first answer.